# ImportError: No module named matplotlib.python-dateutil

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to use py2exe to convert my .pyw to executable file, and 
encountered this error - "ImportError: No module named matplotlib.python-dateutil"

I've installed dateutil before trying to convert this .pyw to .exe,
and .pyw file itself worked fine and produced the expected output, 
but I didn't manage to get the .exe file.

I also have tried put a copy of python-dateutil inside matplotlib folder but still did not solve the problem.

I'm using Python 2.7 and python-dateutil 2.2.

This is my setup.pyw. copied from (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib)

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib

matplotlibdatadir = matplotlib.get_data_path()
matplotlibdata = findall(matplotlibdatadir)
matplotlibdata_files = [] for f in matplotlibdata:
    dirname = os.path.join('matplotlibdata', f[len(matplotlibdatadir)+1:])
    matplotlibdata_files.append((os.path.split(dirname)[0], [f]))


setup(
    windows = ['graph.pyw'],
    options = {
             'py2exe': {
                        'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'pytz'],
                        }
            },
    #data_files = matplotlibdata_files
    data_files = matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles() )
```

Appreciate feedback and ideas..thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please correct the formatting of the code.

Comment: It looks like you hit the block quote button, then the code button. Your code is hopelessly garbled.

Comment: Can you post the exact message (e.g. line that fails etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put matplotlib.python-dateutil in the packages list:

```
'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.python-dateutil', 'pytz'],
```

When this hasn't fixed similar hassles for me, I've sometimes found that you need to wildcard submodules:

```
'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'matplotlib.python-dateutil.*', 'pytz'],
```

YMMV on that one.